# How to outline (silhouette) 3D model in URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

Good weekend everyone, I'm looking for some tutorial/script how to make 3D object outline with original image texture (eg. stick with wood texture). I would like to when the raycast hits the object (I'm able to detect with object is raycast hitted), the object will be outlined/glowed.

[image]

I tryed many tutorials on youtube, finding shaders script, etc, but I'm using URP Unity 2020 and some shaders is not working - only pink material, or works different. Emitter material is not good too, because there is no original texture. I'm stuck on this for few days. I'm a newbie in the Unity community.

Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Outline shaders are difficult to make. I use this free asset I found in the Unity Asset store for all my games if you are looking for an easy fix.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488